# js convert array to object and adding specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, reduce

I have below array

```
let users=[0,1,2];
```

I need to convert it to object like below format

```
{"0":{"id":"0"},"1":{"id":"1"},"2":{"id":"2"},}
```

How i can get this format?

Comment: What is with all those tags? There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) or any vue.js related stuff in the "question".

Comment: What is the rule for the object? Why is there no object with `"id": "0"`?

Comment: It is something you can do with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce); have a go and, if you cannot figure out how to do it, feel free to post your attempted code to receive help.

Comment: Because I am forced to add 5 tags 
@Andreas

Comment: `[0,1,2].reduce((obj, id) => (obj[id] = {id}, obj), {})`

Answer (score 2):

```
let obj = {}
users.forEach(index => {
   obj[index] = {id: index}
})
```

Then convert to Json

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```js
let users = [0, 1, 2];
let obj = {};
users.forEach((user, index) => {
  obj[index] = {
    "id": index
  };
})
console.log(obj)
```

or

```js
let users = [0, 1, 2];
let obj = {};
users.forEach((user, index) => {
  obj['"' + index + '"'] = {
    "id": index
  };
})
console.log(obj)
```